# what is 10147 in Android, it drain battery power 54% in 6 hours

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I have Motog5 plus,and since 2 days battery drain too fast, 
when I see battery information I could not find which app is this so that I can uninstall it.

[image]

Comment: malware probably

Comment: I do not know the reason.

Comment: Still unsolved?

Comment: @esQmo I restarted phone, I have disabled background data for all apps which shows advertisements, till now I have not see same issue again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to click on **10147** to find the next screen i.e. Use details screen. Under this screen you'll find an **information button** on the right hand side beside the title (*in your case it will be 10147*). And if it is a third party application you'll get the option to **Uninstall** it else if it is a system app you may find the option to **disable** it.

Hope this helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a Nandroid backup before you do this if you can.

Comment: I have checked that too, both options were disabled, I could not click on any one of them.